# Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException::$status

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I keep getting this error when trying to get the status of the request.

This is my code

```
ExpenseRepository.php

<?php

namespace Expensetrim\Api\v1\Repositories;

use Auth;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Expensetrim\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ExpenseRepository
{
    private $api_url;

    const API_GET = 'GET';
    const API_POST = 'POST';
    const API_PUT = 'PUT';

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_url = "http://xxx-xxx-xxx/api/v1/";
    }

    public function api_call($method, $uri, $request = NULL)
{
    try {

        $url=$this->api_url.$uri;
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->api_url]);
        $response = ($request) ? $client->request($method, $uri, $request) : $client->request($method, $uri);
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
    return $this->formatResponseBody($response);
}

public static function formatResponseBody($response)
{
    $body = $response->getBody(true)->getContents();
    return json_decode($body);
}

public function addExpenseType($data)
{
    $uri = 'expense/types/add';
    $response = $this->api_call(self::API_POST, $uri, ['form_params' => $data]);
    return $response;

}
```

Also CompanyRepository.php

```
public function addExpenseType($company_id, $data)
    {
        $data['company_id'] = $company_id;
        $expense = new ExpenseRepository;
        $done = $expense->addExpenseType($data);
        if($done->status == 'success') {
          return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I need to check if the status is a success or not but keep getting this error: Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException::$status.
Please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is an exception thrown at this line:

```
catch (RequestException $e) {
    return $e;
}
```

and you are returning the exception. The return value of the method `addExpenseType` is actually an exception thrown by Guzzle.

throw the exception to see the error.
change your code to

```
catch (RequestException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. After changing to what you suggested, i got this error:            
 cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 173.XXX.0 port 80: No route to host (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) .  Any idea

Answer (score 1):

Change your `formatResponseBody` function to add `$response->getBody()->rewind();`

```
public static function formatResponseBody($response)
{
    $response->getBody()->rewind();
    $body = $response->getBody(true)->getContents();
    return json_decode($body);
}
```

In the old version of `guzzle`, it read the full body without resetting the pointer after. Using `rewind()` will reset the pointer. If this is the source of your issue `rewind()` will resolve this. It has aleady been resolved in newer versions.